# Ubuntu Yarn Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'

Tags: ubuntu, node-modules, yarnpkg, corepack

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to install yarn on my machine but I'm getting an error when I try to execute yarn.

Error:

```
fs/promises is not installed
```

Anyone can help check the error code below thank you.

[image: Error img]

I tried installing Promises in global but it didn't work, also uninstalled corepack and yarn and reinstalled back again.

Comment: `fs/promises` is supported since nodejs v10. What version of nodejs do you have installed? Typically you should not install nodejs from the OS-package repository because depending on the distribution they may be quite old.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys but i think i fixed by forcing an instalation of the latest nodejs

Comment: Instead of forcing an install of node globally on your machine, try using Node Version Manager (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) which allows you to run multiple versions of Node on the same machine in sandbox environments.